# Compare two multidimensional Associative arrays

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I've been trying to get this for hours now.
I have two multidimensional arrays.

```
$newData (
[0] => Array(
    [id] => 1
    [name] => John
    [sex] => male
)
[1] => Array(
    [id] => 2
    [name] => Kenny
    [sex] => male
)
[2] => Array(
    [id] => 3
    [name] => Sarah
    [sex] => female
)
[3] => Array(
    [id] => 4
    [name] => George
    [sex] => male
)
)

$oldData (
[0] => Array(
    [id] => 3
    [name] => Sarah
    [sex] => female
)
[1] => Array(
    [id] => 4
    [name] => George
    [sex] => male
)
[2] => Array(
    [id] => 5
    [name] => Peter
    [sex] => male
)
[3] => Array(
    [id] => 6
    [name] => Lexi
    [sex] => female
)
)
```

If name in `$oldData` is matched with `$newData` I need to fetch the id of that array without using more loops

Comment: can you change the structure of the array ?

Comment: Paste what you have done so far.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [array_search()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

which can also return the key of the array you find the match in.

eg

```
$key = array_search($array1['name'], $array2);
```

Comment: that is not even a valid syntax

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam good spot, 6 years late to the party - but updated :P

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not so complicated with loops. If I correctly understood your problem the code will look somehow like this:

```
$matches = array();
foreach($newData as $index => $newItem)
  foreach($oldData as $oldItem)
    if($newData['name'] === $oldItem['name'])
      $matches[] = $index;
```

Answer (score 0):

With two loops it is possible to get the array key.

```
$oldDataCount = count($oldData);

$result = array();

for($i = 0; $i < count($newData); $i++)     
    for($j =0; $j < $oldDataCount; $j++) 
        if ($oldData[$j]['name'] == $newData[$i]['name']) 
            $result[$newData[$i]['name']] = $j;


print_r($result);
```

Now, the array holds the results `Array ( [Sarah] => 0 [George] => 1 )`